React native ITMS-91053
Reading about this subject, it seems that the third party SDK have to do the update and I should not change anything on my side. But as I am not sure if they will make the update on time and I do not want to generate bugs upgrading quickly my versions, I would like to handle it by my side.
It seems creating it directly with Xcode works, but in my case I still have the issues.
I created a App Privacy file using Xcode on my project root with the following content
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
      <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
      <array>
         <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>

            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
               <string>7D9E.1</string>
            </array>
         </dict>
         <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime</string>
            
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
               <string>3D61.1</string>
            </array>
         </dict>
      </array>
   </dict>
</plist>

But then each time I release it with TestFlight, I still have the same error messages

Although submission for TestFlight review was successful, you may want to correct the following issues in your next submission for TestFlight review. Once you've corrected the issues, upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “***” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.
ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “***” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.
Apple Developer Relations


You need to add a privacy manifest for the APIs that your code uses and sdks also need to add a privacy manifest for their SDK use

I have written an article about this that you may find relevant. Can you share your podspec file so that we can see your dependencies? You will need to make sure those dependencies have included a privacy manifest as well.

Yes it could be really useful to know which packages need the API declaration.
As I am using React Native there is a lot of native code in kind of black box I do not know if they need the API declaration. I do not have a  podspec file with React Native, only a Podfile.lock.
From the message from Apple I am unable to know in which package the API declaration is needed
